# How to set the value of input elements (type=text) with browser.tabs.executeScript on a sign in page

Tags: javascript

I want to insert a username to any given sign-in page from an extension. The extension obtains the relevant username from a server and sends it to the active tab using `browser.tabs.executeScript(code: "code here")`. I am working with Firefox only at present.

I have put the code [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rusty1642/rn3adzut/6/), and I have tried a simpler version excluding the matching of id, title, name and placeholder but I still can't achieve that.

```
function insertCredentials(password, userName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='password']");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].value = password;
}
  //assume only 1 type=email input
  var y = document.querySelector("input[type='email']");
  y.value = userName;

  var z = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
  //test for user in name
  if (z[i].name.match(/user/ig)) {
     z[i].value = userName;
  }
  //test for user in title
  if (z[i].title.match(/user/ig)) {
     z[i].value = userName;
  }
  //test for user in id
  if (z[i].id.match(/user/ig)) {
    z[i].value = userName;
  }
  //test for user in placeholder
  if (z[i].placeholder.match(/user/ig)) {
     z[i].value = userName;
  }
 }
}
```

The code obtains all inputs with `type=email` or `type=text` in the active tab into a nodelist or variable.

It loops the elements and if `type=text` it tests for the string 'user' (case insensitive) in name or id or title or placeholder attributes. If a match is found the element's value is set to the user name sent with the code.

The injected script correctly identifies inputs where `type=email` and sets the value accordingly (it also works fine where `type=password`), but it does not identify inputs where (for instance) `type=text` and `id=username` or `name=userID` or `placeholder="email or username here.."`, and leaves them blank.

The Firefox browser does correctly populate the user field when I allow the browser to save the login during testing.

Why does this script not identify `type=text` inputs?